# show child element right after implementation

Tags: javascript

```
var firstMove = 0;
var pictures = ['boar.jpg','lion.jpg','bones.jpg','eagle.jpg','wolf.jpg','boar.jpg','lion.jpg','bones.jpg','eagle.jpg','wolf.jpg','boar.jpg','lion.jpg','bones.jpg','eagle.jpg','wolf.jpg']
pictures.sort()
function replyClick(clicked_id)
{
  //if player already draw one card;
  if (firstMove){
    var image = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    image.innerHTML = '<img src='+pictures[clicked_id-1]+' />'
    var firstPicture = document.getElementById(firstMove);
    if (image.innerHTML == firstPicture.innerHTML){
        firstMove=0;

    }
    else {
      image.innerHTML = "";
      firstPicture.innerHTML = "";
      firstMove=0
    }

  }
  // if player didnt draw any card;
  else {
    var image = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    image.innerHTML = '<img src='+pictures[clicked_id-1]+' />'
    firstMove = clicked_id
  }
}


<div class="card" id="1" onclick="replyClick(this.id)"></div>
<div class="card" id="2" onclick="replyClick(this.id)"></div>
```

I try to create simple pexeso game.where you looking for two identical images.

My question is how to change this code to show that certain image right after somebody click on it.Because my script show image after inner condition but that is too late for me.Thanks for answer

Comment: So `id` is the index in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare array elements.

```
pictures[clicked_id-1] == pictures[firstMove-1]
```

is the same that

```
image.innerHTML == firstPicture.innerHTML
```

**UPD**
For small delay use `setTimeout`

```
// other code
function replyClick(clicked_id) {
    if (firstMove){
        var imageSrc = pictures[clicked_id-1];
        var prevImageSrc = pictures[firstMove-1];

        var image = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
        image.innerHTML = '<img src='+imageSrc+' />'
        var firstPicture = document.getElementById(firstMove);

        if (imageSrc == prevImageSrc) {
            firstMove=0;
        } else {
            // code will run after 1s delay
            setTimeout(function () {
                image.innerHTML = "";
                firstPicture.innerHTML = "";
                firstMove=0;
            }, 1000); // delay = 1 second
        }

    } else {
        var image = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
        image.innerHTML = '<img src='+pictures[clicked_id-1]+' />'
        firstMove = clicked_id
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't compare clicked_id == firstMove because there are different numbers. firstMove is number first picture and when this number is different from 0 that to condition with second clicked_id

Comment: thanks for update condition it works.But it still not resolved my problem. I want to show this picture for couple second before it execute this part             else {
      image.innerHTML = "";
      firstPicture.innerHTML = "";
      firstMove=0
    }